# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) when locating a file

Tags: javascript, iframe, download, server, http-status-code-404

I am currently on the page

```
Leader/Index.html
```

I want to access and have the file download from here:

```
Leader/Data.csv
```

I have code in my javascript file that creates an iframe with the file path I think is correct and create the IFrame, but the server responds with the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://localhost:49635/Leader/Data.csv
```

I think the path is correct, and don't understand why it's not downloading. Here is the javascript code:

```
var downloadFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");

if (downloadFrame != null) {
downloadFrame.setAttribute("src", '../Data.csv');
downloadFrame.style.width = "0px";
downloadFrame.style.height = "0px";
document.body.appendChild(downloadFrame);
}
```

I have tried changing the path from "../Data.csv" to "Data.csv" to no avail.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what server are you using to serve files? does it have a restriction on the content types it's allowed to serve? will it load if you go directly to that URL in your browser?

Comment: @kirinthos It's an ASP.NET MVC App using IIS. I'm not sure where I would look to find the restriction on content types.

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with MVC, but perhaps you could [start with serving static files](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html#serving-static-files) which talks about authorizing static file access

Comment: **Solved:** I changed the file location to the root folder in the website, and set the file path to ../../Data.csv which solved the problem. I don't know why it gave me so much trouble how I had it, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends where your JS file is placed. If it is in the same directory as Index.html and Data.csv then you should use

```
downloadFrame.setAttribute("src", "./Data.csv");
```

Also, on second though, I don't think that you can just put csv in the Iframe source and hope it will work. 
Look at this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34801182/3967800